# Use R/exams exams2pdf() to produce a PDF document

Tags: r, r-exams

I am new to the R/exams package and I try to produce a pdf document from one of the templates provided by the developers. (http://www.R-exams.org/templates/confint3/)

I am able to compile a Rnw file into a HTML document using the commands

```
library("exams")
exams2html("confint3.Rnw")
```

When calling the function 
`exams2pdf("confint3.Rnw")`
it gives the error message

```
! LaTeX Error: File `Sweave.sty' not found.
```

I have Latex installed and there are no problems using it in general. I do not understand:

1. Do I need to tell `exams2pdf()` the location of the latex installation?
2. Do I need to define a template (as `plain.tex`) first? How should it look like?
3. What is it that I do not understand?

I looked at the documentation of the exams package, I also tried `exams2pdf()` after installing and calling `library("tinytex")`.

Any help where to look at or what to do is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Minimal example:

```
install.packages("exams")
install.packages("tth")
library("exams")

set.seed(1090)
exams2html("confint3.Rnw")
set.seed(1090)
exams2pdf("confint3.Rnw")
```

Comment: I'm on an Ubuntu box and am unable to reproduce. I get a nice pdf document. Linux bosxes are more likely to be equiped for Latex opeations from the getgo than are Mac or Windoze boxes. Kudos for trying to create a running example, but the install process for `exams` package fails to also install the `tth` package. Apparently the package authors missed that requirement in their dependencies.

Comment: @AchimZeileis: Since the package maintainer is a sometimes contributor to SO, If the "SO-pin" doesn't attract his attention then you can use the maintainer info at the package DESCRIPTION: Achim.Zeileis at R-project.org

Comment: Thank you @IRTFM for correcting my question and the minimal example. I should have be more precise about the package dependencies, right. As far as I understand this is not the source of the error message, I had the the tth package installed.

Comment: Thank you again @IRTFM, I thought of contacting Achim Zeileis but I wanted to post my question here first.

Comment: It turned out that the 'tth'-pkg was only needed for the first function call: `exams2html` and that Achim was aware of this and therefore only had 'tth' in Suggests rather than Imports, so really my error and not his.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to diagnose what exactly goes wrong with the information provided. In any case, when running pdfLaTeX either through `utils::texi2dvi()` (the default when the R package `tinytex` is not installed) or through `tinytex::latexmk()` (the default when the R package `tinytex` is installed) does not find the `Sweave.sty` file provided by the R base system. What is not clear to me which LaTeX engine is running in the background: MikTeX on Windows?

There are several strategies that could resolve this issue:

- Tell your LaTeX installation about the `texmf` directory provided by the R base system so that it is found no matter where on your system you call pdfLaTeX.
- Use a different LaTeX installation, e.g., by installing TinyTeX (the LaTeX distribution) through `tinytex` (the R package): `tinytex::install_tinytex()`. This might be particularly attractive if you are not actually a LaTeX user and just need it to compile PDF exams.
- Avoid using the `Sweave.sty` file in a custom template file, say `myplain.tex`. A suggestion for such a file is included at the end of this post.

Further details are discussed in this thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153193/latex-error-sweave-sty-not-found

As for your three questions:

1. As already explained above: `exams2pdf()` leverages either `utils::texi2dvi()` or `tinytex::latexmk()`. So these need to know about the LaTeX installation - but this seems to be the case. They just don't find the `texmf` provided by base R.
2. You should not *have* to do this but it is certainly an option that you *can* use. As a starting point, run `exams_skeleton(markup = "latex", writer = "exams2pdf")`. Among other things this creates a `templates` folder where you could put the `myplain.tex` template below.
3. As I said above, it's hard to answer that with the information provided. Hopefully, one of the clues provided here gets you a couple of steps forward.

Content of `myplain.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{a4wide,graphicx,color,verbatim,url,fancyvrb,ae,amsmath,amssymb,booktabs,longtable,eurosym}
\newenvironment{question}{\item \textbf{Problem}\newline}{}
\newenvironment{solution}{\textbf{Solution}\newline}{}
\newenvironment{answerlist}{\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
\providecommand{\tightlist}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}

\setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Sinput}{Verbatim}{fontshape=sl}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Soutput}{Verbatim}{}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Scode}{Verbatim}{fontshape=sl}
\newenvironment{Schunk}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
%% \exinput{exercises}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @Achim Zeileis! Thank you for your immediate reply and for formatting my question. I forget to mention that I use MacTeX on Mac OS. I use R and Latex extensively for my research and teaching for years and I already looked at the link you provided me, thank you. I am not sure that it addresses my problem but I will look at all your other suggestions.

Comment: @IRTFM Thanks for your support with this. Regarding the problems with the `tth` installation: I would need more details to say something about this. Please feel free to report this by e-mail or post the details elsewhere.

Comment: @n.small In that case I would recommend to _not_ install the TinyTeX distribution. Instead as a short-term workaround you can use your own LaTeX template (like the `myplain.tex` that I posted). Additionally I would recommend to resolve the problem that `Sweave.sty` cannot be found. Possibly the suggestion from user chan1142 in the discussion linked above might work for you...

Comment: Thank you @Achim Zeileis. The tex-Template you provided  solved my problem after putting it into my R working directory. Still I understand that this is a work around and that I have not grasped the complexity of my problem yet, but for now I am able to produce a series of randomized versions of one of your templates.

Comment: Concerning the problem that Sweave.sty cannot be found, this message never showed up before. I write all me lecture notes using knitr. Still I will at your recommendation in order to better understand the whole setup! I already have installed TinyTeX though...

Comment: I'll send you the console transcript but my attempts to remove `tth`-pkg and reproduce the error are failing. Furthermore, I'm using an out-of-date R, I was doing this in a session with almost 80 loaded packages, and it was in Rstudio so feel free to file this in the appropriate bin.

Comment: `knitr` does not use `Sweave.sty` by default (i.e., not unless you tell it it to). I would recommend that you search for `Sweave.sty` in the `share/texmf/` directory that is provided by your R installation. And then you should add that directory to your `texhash`. I cannot provide more details because I have never used OS X/MacTeX.

Comment: @AchimZeileis  .. Maybe I should see what trouble I can get into on my Mac? It's also not up-to-date but I doubt this configuration issue is arising just because the OP is using Catalina.

Comment: I think it is just an environment variable that is not set properly which results in R's `share/texmf/` not being included in the texmf paths. Why this can happen and how to best resolve it on OS X with MacTeX I don't know, unfortunately.

Comment: I am aware of that ```knitr```does not use ```Sweave.sty```. That is why I was puzzled about the message given my Weave options/settings in R-Studio. Following your suggestion @AchimZeileis I used the instructions from http://www.jason-french.com/blog/2013/08/16/easy-sweaving-for-latex-and-r/ and I am now able to run the minimal example from my initial question. Perfect!
@AchimZeileis and @IRTFM thank your immediate support and for providing this highly useful R package!

Comment: OK, good! Regarding the Weave option settings in RStudio. These influence weaving/knitting buttons in RStudio but not the behavior of other packages. In R/exams the default is to use `Sweave()` for .Rnw files to keep dependencies simple and because the extended facilities of `knitr` are typically not needed for most exams. However, you can set the `engine = "knitr"` if you want in `exams2pdf()`. Nevertheless, this will still invoke the `knitr::render_sweave()` compatibility option.